# How to display a PDF which is in a string?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app using Java.

PDF is in the string, like some code, you can see here:

```
1 0 obj
   [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
   endobj
   13 0 obj
   << /Length 1600 /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream
   x��X�nSG�_�w�����K���BmD q�D�K|�:q�:�Jy�>B���̜�o
```

What I want to do is to display PDF in any way, it doesn't matter if it's visible in a PDF field or in WebView.

Comment: If you have a PDF document in a `String` then you've already messed up (unless it's Base64 encoded or something like that). It should be in a `byte[]`. `String`is used for readable text which the PDF format is not.

Comment: Yes, interesting. How did the pdf content get there? If you have no choice but have to accept it as a string, you can convert it to bytes again.

Comment: I get it from an HTTP request like that, but I put it in String, where should I put it? @JoachimSauer

Comment: @Niklaus: HTTP only ever transports bytes, possibly with some encoding information attached. So something converts those bytes to a `String` somewhere: make sure that's not done, but you don't show us *how* you get it from HTTP so we can't tell you where you went wrong.